# How to sent image using XMPPStream XMPP Framework in Swift Language?

Tags: ios, image, sockets, xmppframework

I used

> pod 'XMPPFramework'

in my Demo Project. I made connections, and put delegate methods appropriately.

I made simple chat, where I am sending message using

```
 let msg = XMPPMessage(type: "chat", to: senderJID)
 msg.addBody(message)
 self.appDelegate.xmppStream.sendElement(msg)
```

On receiving end, I am doing

```
func xmppStream(sender: XMPPStream!, didReceiveMessage message: XMPPMessage!) {

messageStr = messageStr + message.body()
print("Did receive message \(messageStr)")

}
```

Now I want to sent Image. I browsed and found some code, using attachment, like below, in objective-c.

```
NSData *dataF = UIImagePNGRepresentation(SendImage);
         NSString *imgStr=[dataF base64Encoding];

         NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
         [body setStringValue:messageStr];

         NSXMLElement *imgAttachement = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"attachment"];
         [imgAttachement setStringValue:imgStr];

         NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
         [message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
         [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:chatWithUser];
         [message addChild:body];
         [message addChild:imgAttachement];      

         [self.xmppStream sendElement:message];
```

My Swift code , which I converted from above Objective-C Code.

```
var dataF = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
        var imgStr = dataF.base64Encoding()

        let root = NSXMLElement(name: "find_sites")

        var body = NSXMLElement.elementWithName("body")
        body.stringValue = messageStr
        var imgAttachement = NSXMLElement.elementWithName("attachment")
        imgAttachement.stringValue = imgStr
        var message = NSXMLElement.elementWithName("message")
        message.addAttributeWithName("type", stringValue: "chat")
        message.addAttributeWithName("to", stringValue: senderJID)
        message.addChild(body)
        message.addChild(imgAttachement)
        self.xmppStream.sendElement(message)
```

If I convert this code into Swift, I am getting error on NSXMLElement, what should I do, how can I achieve it.

I also read `XMPPStream class`, I didn't find anything productive.

Thanks.

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: Use of unresolved identifier 'NSXMLElement'. I also changed code to Swift, let me add swift code in question too.

Comment: try using  `XMPPMessage` class

Comment: XMPPMessage which is in Core of XMPPFramework

Comment: I am using XMPPMessage, in simple Text, while for Image, i can't find any method in library.

Answer (score 2):

You can use DDXMLElement instead of NSXMLElement.

```
    let body = DDXMLElement.element(withName: "body") as! DDXMLElement
    let imageAttachement = DDXMLElement.element(withName: "attachment", stringValue: imageStr!) as! DDXMLElement

    let message = DDXMLElement.element(withName: "message") as! DDXMLElement
    message.addAttribute(withName: "type", stringValue: "chat")
    message.addAttribute(withName: "to", stringValue: receiver)
    message.addChild(body)
    message.addChild(imageAttachement)
```

Comment: I have send the image using this code but how can i  read xmpp data ?